# get updated changed html from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

long time reader first time asker....

If I have a textarea with html text in it (I am trying to verify certain elements have an id) and I send that code to a function how do i update that textarea with the new changes?

I have tried wrapping it in a div from previous suggestions I read here, but its not showing me the updated html.

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gk6yLh77/

```
function runfunc(){
 var uniqueIdFind = '<div>'+jQuery('#pages_htmlcode_content').val()+'</div>';var curDateEpochSec='12112';
 if(jQuery('#content-wrapper',uniqueIdFind).length==1){
  jQuery('#content-wrapper',uniqueIdFind).find('[onclick], [href]').not('link').not('a[nostat],[statproc],a[href="#top"]').each(function(index){
   if(!jQuery(this,uniqueIdFind).attr('id')){console.log('id======dd_'+curDateEpochSec+'_'+index);jQuery(this,uniqueIdFind).attr('id','dd_'+curDateEpochSec+'_'+index);}
  });
  jQuery('#pages_htmlcode_content2').val(uniqueIdFind);
 }else{
  alert('erros')
 }
}
```

I put a console write in the function and can see the id's being added, but for the life of me I can not figure out how to get those changes.

here is the sample html to put into the first textarea

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
</head>
<body id="com">
  <div id="top" class="landing-page">
  </div>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
   <div id="content-main">
    <a href="dssdfsdf" class="asda">asdasad</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It just spits out the original code :(

Thanks

Comment: You are setting the `context` at `jQuery()` call to a string

Comment: sorry not following ... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neeed to wrap your test element in `$()`

example:

```
if(jQuery(uniqueIdFind).find('#content-wrapper').length==1)
```

Comment: but that first part passes, it gets passed that part, what I cant get is the updated html from the original textarea... the textarea (2) shows the same content

Comment: what is this supposed to do? Demo doesn't work and there is no explanation of expected results

Comment: you need to wrap the html once. in `$()`..and store in a variable. Then modify inside it as needed...then undo it using `html()` on that variable

Comment: sorry i gave the textarea a name ... uggg
there is a button there (i promise ... LOL) ... I am taking the html I provided above, and pasting it into the first textarea at the top, then hitting the "NO NAME" button, and expect the results in the textarea below with each <a> element having anew id if it did not have one.

Sorry for confusion, first time question asker and was a little quick on the draw to hit the submit i think :(

Comment: charlietfl sorry I am not following :(

Comment: charlietfl ok great, with your example I was able to learn from it to do mine. Thats great. I will work harder on my demos and better explain myself going forward. GRATS!